# Can you identify this freehub from a 2014 Boardman CX Comp?

Tags: freehub

[image: Images of freehub]

I need to replace this freehub from my 2014 Boardman CX Comp as it's becoming incredibly sticky.

There's not a lot to identify it. It's stamped 'M M P' on the side. Trial and error has found an 11mm hex key to fit the the central spline to remove it. It's a 9-speed cassette.

I expect it's some kind of generic, relatively cheap hub but don't know enough about such things to identify a suitable replacement.

Comment: You might have some luck writing the company and asking who their hub OEM is.

Comment: Looks similar to a Sram 506 (Treefort Bikes)

Answer (score 6):

I made a guess. it turned out correct:

**Trek/Bontrager (Select) Freehub Body 561948 (repl W268886)**

Available from [Pedalon](https://www.pedalon.co.uk/acatalog/bontrager-select-freehub.html) (where I ordered from) or [GB Cycles](https://www.gbcycles.co.uk/p/118251/Trek-Bontrager-Freehub-Body-561948-(repl-W268886)) (from whose catalogue I figured it out).

GB Cycles listed a few similar alternatives but they can be discounted:

- [561949](https://www.gbcycles.co.uk/p/118771/Trek-Bontrager-Freehub-Body-561949) is 11-speed (although worryingly listed a 130mm OLD, whereas my bike is 135mm OLD - but there are no sizes on the 561948)
- [W268886](https://www.gbcycles.co.uk/p/43549/Trek-Bontrager-W268886-SSR-SSTK-SL-Freehub-Body) has been superseded by the 561948
- [W211339](https://www.gbcycles.co.uk/p/43562/Trek-Bontrager-Freehub-Body-W211339) has sealed cartridge bearings

I'm still waiting for Boardman to come up with an actual part number or Halfords reference, although it's a moot point now.

I've only actually done a quick test fitting tonight, but the freehub fits the existing hub and the cassette fits on the freehub, so I think I'm good.

<s>Not a direct answer, but I called up Boardman. Not entirely surprised they didn't have a part number, but they were able to offer up a reference with which I could order from Halfords. They have me the usual runaround, but hopefully should have something that fits middle of next week. In the meantime I guess I'll continue getting fat.</s>

> Boardman's reference on Halford's system: **341740**
>
> Receipt description: "**FHB CB/Car/VD Splin F th**"
>
> Cost: **£19.99**

Except it turns out that doesn't fit. Different gender. Drat.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This freehub came off a Giant SR-2 wheel, a 700c alloy.  "N L" is stamped on one of the splines of this one. It's my backup wheel for my Trek road bike.  I believe the SR-2 wheels were stock on older model Defy's or Contend models.

[image]

The following picture is a freehub from a Freedom RLX 1.9 alloy, 700c wheel. This freehub has "C a 5" stamped on one spline. The hub itself is devoid of clues as to brand or maker. I bought the wheelset at a rummage sale and the history of it is unknown to me.  However, googling the wheel's make and model, one learns that these rims were apparently stock on a few models of Raleigh road bikes circa 2008, and Freedom  rims often sport Joytech hubs.  FWIW

As with so many things in bicycling and bikes, there are a multitude of variations of the freehub, and saying you'd like a Shimano style/compatible freehub narrows the options very little.  Now days having a nice road rim built in the 8-9-10 speed era and wanting to update to 11 speed, may require getting a new freehub for the wheel (an 11 speed cassette requires more room  to properly fit on a freehub: ~36mm as opposed to old spec of ~34mm). It can be a nightmare finding a compatible 11speed freehub that'll simply swap out with the old one. Sometimes there isn't an11 speed option that will work. Equally suspicious and maddening is that this problem seems to plague the higher-end wheels/wheelsets.  For those that happily roll on budget friendly wheels and want to simply replace a tired or broken freehub, like for like, you'll find the prices for a good many aftermarket freehubs are such that buying a whole new wheel is cheaper![image]